# .css properties to anchor form button outside of table within the form

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use float or some other way to get a form button to appear outside of the table below:

```
<form action="./deleteentry.php" method="post">
    <?php
        foreach ($dbr as $var) {
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $var["title"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $var["year"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $var["author"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $var["condition"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $var["genre"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $var["publisher"]; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="order" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
    <?php
        $i++;
        }
    ?>
<br /><br />
<div class="delshift">
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</div>
</form>
```

The final product should look like the below image. What .css properties should my form/div have? Currently my div has:

```
.delshift{
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
```

[image: visual representation of my issue]
Sorry for the large image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted above is not valid html (no table element wrapping your tr tags) ... however, if you wrap your tr's in a table and float the table left, and then also float your div that contains the submit button left, you should be able to make it work.

The basic structure would be:

```
<form>
    <table style="float:left;">
        <?php code ?>
    </table>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. It was a goof on my part; thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
<form action="./deleteentry.php" method="post">
<div style="width:100%;">    
<?php
        foreach ($dbr as $var) {
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $var["title"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $var["year"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $var["author"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $var["condition"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $var["genre"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $var["publisher"]; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="order" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
    <?php
        $i++;
        }
    ?>
<br /><br />
</div>
<div class="delshift">
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: This makes the "confirm" button appear above the table to the left. I'm trying to get it below the table to the right.

Answer (score 1):

use float left for div its contain table

```
<div style="float:left">
<form action="./deleteentry.php" method="post">
   <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>

            </tr>
   </table>
<br /><br />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</div>
</form>
```